# What's the purpose of align C++ pointer position

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I am now reading the source code of OPENCV, a computer vision open source library. I am confused with this function:

```
#define CV_MALLOC_ALIGN 16
void* fastMalloc( size_t size )
{
    uchar* udata = (uchar*)malloc(size + sizeof(void*) + CV_MALLOC_ALIGN);
    if(!udata)
        return OutOfMemoryError(size);
    uchar** adata = alignPtr((uchar**)udata + 1, CV_MALLOC_ALIGN);
    adata[-1] = udata;
    return adata;
}

/*!
  Aligns pointer by the certain number of bytes

  This small inline function aligns the pointer by the certian number of bytes by
  shifting it forward by 0 or a positive offset.
 */
template<typename _Tp> static inline _Tp* alignPtr(_Tp* ptr, int n=(int)sizeof(_Tp))
{
    return (_Tp*)(((size_t)ptr + n-1) & -n);
}
```

`fastMalloc` is used to allocated memory for a pointer, which invoke `malloc` function and then `alignPtr`. I cannot understand well why `alignPtr` is called after memory is allocated? My basic understanding is by doing so it is much faster for the machine to find the pointer. Can some references on this issue be found in the internet? For modern computer, is it still necessary to perform this operation? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe for caching or special instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some platforms require certain types of data to appear on certain byte boundaries (e.g:- some compilers
require *pointers to be stored on 4-byte boundaries*).

This is called alignment, and it calls for extra padding within, and possibly at the end of, the object's data.

Compiler might break in case they didn't find proper alignment OR there could be performance bottleneck in reading that data ( as there would be a need to read two blocks for getting same data).

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:-

Memory request by a program is generally handled by memory allocator. One such memory allocator is `fixed-size allocator`. Fixed size allocation return chunks of specified size even if requested memory is less than that particular size. So, with that background let me try to explain what's going on here:-

```
uchar* udata = (uchar*)malloc(size + sizeof(void*) + CV_MALLOC_ALIGN);
```

This would allocate amount of memory which is equal to `memory_requested + random_size`. Here `random_size` is filling up the gap to make it fit for size specified for fixed allocation scheme.

```
uchar** adata = alignPtr((uchar**)udata + 1, CV_MALLOC_ALIGN);
```

This is trying to align pointer to specific boundary as explained above.

Comment: Not only compilers, but CPUs too.

Comment: But the object is allocated through `malloc` that already returns a pointer *suitably aligned [...] for any type of object* (C99, 7.20.3p1).

Comment: @ouah: It's probably to align something on a larger boundary for cache alignment purposes.

Comment: "For any type of object" does not include for instance float numbers loaded using `movaps` instructions, which require for instance 16-byte alignment.

Answer (score 1):

It allocates a block a bit bigger than it was asked for.

Then it sets `adata` to the address of the next properly allocated byte (add one byte, then round up to the next properly aligned address).

Then it stores the original pointer before the new address. I assume this is later used to free the originally allocated block.

And then we return the new address.

This only makes sense if `CV_MALLOC_ALIGN` is a stricter alignment than `malloc` guarantees - perhaps a cache line?